# Why won't this scanner accept input on the println?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

When my application compiles, it will not accept the input for `roomNum` on the same line in which it asks, "Please enter a room to search for:"

```
System.out.println();
if(roomNum < 0);   
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a room to search for: ");
    roomNum = input.nextInt();
}
```

If I just use `next` instead of `nextInt`, it doesn't compile correctly.

The code above works, but will not accept the input on the same line which is the functionality I need.

Comment: Remove that semicolon on the `if` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things: Remove semi-colon after `if` condition and use `System.out.print()` instead if you want input on the same line.

Comment: Thanks @akaHuman. That did it. I'm a newb! learned somethin new today.